# How to view subdivision lines in 3d perspective grid?

Tags: interface, 3d-view

I have just installed blender 2.71 and was playing with the grid settings in the display panel. No matter how far I zoom in or out, I am unable to see the subdivision lines in perspective mode. How can I view them?

This image from a tutorial on katsbits.com, you can see the subdivisions in the grid floor. Notice he is in perspective mode.

[image]

Comment: In perspective view these lines make no sense hence they are not drawn.

Answer (score 6):

To get major/minor grids in perspective mode like the image in my original post, simply change the lines setting from the default 16 to something larger (like 100). Basically you are only seeing the minor lines in default view. By adding more lines you will see the major grid appear.

Thanks to everyone for your help.

Answer (score 5):

To see the grid you have to be in [orthographic](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/3D_View) view mode, and in one of the primary views, Front, Top, Right and the inverse Back, Bottom, and Left.

**[Documentation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/3D_View#Rotating_the_View) on the view port**
<kbd>NumPad 5</kbd> to toggle orthographic and perspective view.
<kbd>NumPad 1</kbd> Front view
<kbd>NumPad 3</kbd> Right view
<kbd>NumPad 7</kbd> Top view
Holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> will invert the view, to give back, left, and bottom.

However the Grid Floor is always visible.

Comment: Check the image in my original post. Notice how he seems to be in perspective mode.